# adobe premiere playback lag

Tags: premiere, playback

Having some trouble with video playback. Was wondering if anyone has settings suggestions to help solve the problem. Just trying to play the project in premiere lags even with the resolution downgraded. Any suggestions would be great.

Computer specs:

- Intel Core i7-5820K running @ 4,124 MHz, logical processors 12
- 2x GeForce GTX 980 cards 4,096 MB in SLI
- Memory 32,768 MB @ 2,332 MHz
- 64-bit Windows 10
- M.2 512GB

Video files: 60 fps @ 4096x2048 uncompressed

Nothing spikes, memory runs low and has about 28.9 gigs allocated, processors run low, video cards run low in mem and processors, using mercury. I'm guessing it's some settings that are causing it. I know I'm not using a quarto card which has better drivers for this type if thing ( video drivers are updated ).

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncompressed 4K video at 60fps requires your playback system to deliver approximately 2GB/sec (or more than 15 Gbps).  You can use Blackmagic Design's Disk Speed Test (part of the Desktop Video bundle you can find [here](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/family/capture-and-playback)) to see whether your system meets this criteria.  If it does not, then you'll need to compress your video until you have a bitrate that your IO system can actually support.

Comment: Or get a disk array that is fast enough. Multiple striped ssd should sustain that data rate I guess.

Comment: Even the Samsung evo 950 pro m.2 drive, with a read speed of 2200mb/s is dangerously close to the required speed, so I think a 5xsata ssd raid 0 or a 2x m.2 configuration would be safe, speed wise. That is, if you have 5 sata ports (or two m.2 slots)

Comment: That is for simple playback only though. If you want to edit that footage in realtime, a simple dissolve will require two streams to be read simultaneously, so 4gb/s.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I'm not on skylake so I'm unable to raid m.2, but I will be needing more space anyways. I ran some test on my internal raid setup and the m.2, they are no where near fast enough. I'm going to look into an external raid 0 ssd array. It seems like then the bottle neck will be data transfer speed. Maybe I can find a usb 3.1 external raid array. Any recommendations for a unit, or experience with solid speedy ssd I usually go with the Samsung 850 Evo ?

Comment: I thought I should post some benchmarks encase anyone else comes across the post. This shows my m.2 vs. a 6x HDD Raid 0 speeds. This was not tested properly, I had a lot going on during the test.
https://stlz.s3.amazonaws.com/storage-drive.jpg